# C - Print ordered 3-Anagrams of a string in a binary search tree

Tags: c, string, binary-search-tree

This code in C have in input an integer and a string and should give in output all the anagrams of 3 consecutive letters of the strings in lexicographic order.

```
EXAMPLE:
Input
3
mississippi
Output
ipp
iss
iss
mis
ppi
sip
sis
ssi
ssi
```

It doesn't, instead it gives only the last 3-gram repeted n times with n=the number of 3-grams possible.

I used a binary search tree of strings to memorize every anagram, i can't use a simple array of strings because the exercise requires so. To print the strings in order it proceed with a simmetric visit (from left to right).

I made some debug test and i think the problem is araund the insertion function, probably i made a mess with punctators.

If somebody wants to take a look i would be grateful

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
  char * key;
  int dim;
  struct nodo * left;
  struct nodo * right;
} Nodo;
typedef Nodo* albero;


/*int dimensions (albero t)
{
  int d;
  if (t==NULL) return 0;
  else d=(1+dimensions(t->left)+dimensions(t->right));
  t->dim=d;
  return d;
}*/

simmetrica(albero t,int z)
{
  if (t!=NULL)
  {
  simmetrica(t->left,z);
  /*if ((t->dim)>=z)*/ printf("%s\n",t->key);
  simmetrica(t->right,z);
  }
}

Nodo* insert(albero t, char* key)
{
  Nodo* new = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  new->key=key;
  new->dim=0;
  new->right=NULL;
  new->left=NULL;
  if(t==NULL)
    {
      return new;
    }
  Nodo* parent;
  Nodo* current=t;
  while(current!=NULL)
    {
      parent=current;
      if/*(current->key<key)*/(strcmp(current->key,key)<0)
        {
          current=current->right;
        }
      else
        {
          current=current->left;
        }
    }
  if/*(parent->key<key)*/(strcmp(parent->key,key)<0)
    {
      parent->right=new;
    }
  else parent->left=new;
  return t;
}




int main()
{
  int z;
  char s[501];
  char trip[4];
  albero t=malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  t=NULL;
  scanf("%d", &z);
  scanf("%s", s);
  int o=0;
  while (s[o+2] !='\0')
  { //printf("debug %d\n",o);
    trip[0]=s[o];
    trip[1]=s[o+1];
    trip[2]=s[o+2];
    trip[3]='\0';
    //printf("trip %s\n",trip);
    t=insert(t, trip);
    o++;
  }
  //dimensions(t);
  simmetrica(t,z);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all about storage.  `trip` has storage allocated to it.  It exists at some address, lets pretend its `0x401fc`.  When you do an insert, you pass the address `0x401fc` into `insert`.  Insert makes a new record of type `struct nodo` and copies the address `0x401fc` into the field `key`.

Then you move on and change the values in `trip` which change the values at `0x401fc` and now all the `struct nodo` are pointing to the new values.

Either do a `new-> key= strdup(key)` or have `struct nodo` have a `char key[4] ;` and do a `strcpy()`.  Either solution creates new storage.  The first is a simpler fix in the short term, but would be more work to dispose of (since its separate storage from the struct).  The second form requires more initial changes, but would make de-allocating your memory easier.

Comment: Great! I just changed `new->key=key;` with  `new-> key= strdup(key);` now it seems to work fine, as i expected i just have noob punctators skills, thanks!

Comment: Ehm yeah, I don't want it to sound like an excuse but as you probably have understood i'm not native english speaking.